# First fundamental form

Tags: differential-geometry

Wolfram MathWorld defines a [paraboloid](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParaboloidGeodesic.html)
and its differential parameters as

\begin{align*}
 P&=\left(\frac{\partial x}{du}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial y}{du}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial z}{du}\right)^2= \\
&=1+\frac{1}{4u} \\
 Q&=\frac{\partial x}{du}\frac{\partial x}{dv}+\frac{\partial y}{du}\frac{\partial y}{dv}+\frac{\partial z}{du}\frac{\partial z}{dv}= \\
&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}(\cos v - \sin v) \\
 R&=\left(\frac{\partial x}{dv}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial y}{dv}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial  z}{dv}\right)^2= \\
&=u \\
\end{align*}

Now, if these parameters correspond to the coefficients $E$, $F$ and $G$ described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_fundamental_form), I don't understand how they arrived at the expression for $Q$.

Comment: I see... Nevermind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite other comments/answers, these quantities *are* the usual first fundamental form. Note that the Wiki link defines $g_{ij} = X_i\cdot X_j$. These are the usual $E,F,G$, and they are the dot products of the derivatives of the parametrization with respect to the independent variables. In your case the first parameter is $u$ and the second parameter is $v$, and we do in fact have
\begin{align*}
P&=X_u\cdot X_u=E,\\
Q&=X_u\cdot X_v=F, \quad\text{and} \\ 
R&=X_v\cdot X_v=G.
\end{align*}
I'm not sure why Wolfram is using different letters.

If you want a further reference, check out my [differential geometry text](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up!  When I plug in the parametrization given in the first [link](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParaboloidGeodesic.html) I don't know how they arrive at that non-zero expression for $Q$ (or $F$). I double-checked the partial derivatives but I still don't see it.

Comment: You're right. It's garbage. The parameter curves are orthogonal (as you can see pictorially) and $F=0$.

Comment: FWIW, I figured it out where MathWorld went wrong: instead of calculating the product of the partial derivatives, e.g. $\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}$, it is $\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\right)$, same for the other terms. Thanks again, Ted.

Answer (score 1):

The first fundamental form is the inner product of the tangent space in some point of the surface when you consider the surface contained in the ambient space $\mathbb{R}^3$. If you have a paraboloid $z=b(x^2+y^2)$, then the tangent vectors of the surface which generates the tangent space are

$v=[1,0, 2bx]$

and

$w=[0,1,2by]$

At this point the coefficients of the first fundamental form can be computed as follows

$E=\langle v, v \rangle=1+4b^2x^2$

$F=4b^2xy $

$G=1+4b^2y^2$

In your link about paraboloid, I guess the argument is a geodesic on the paraboloid.